# DOM help, parents of parents, children of children

Tags: javascript

I am using Drupal's Webform module which writes all the ids and classes automatically, so I can't add an Id to the place I want to add it.  And Drupal doesn't put one in for me.  Grrr.

I have no problem when I use my code with just a simple getElementById('myid'), but the element I need is a blank, no id, no class "a" that's inside a "legend" (which has a class but no id) that's inside a fieldset with an id.

I tried this code and several variations but it didn't work:

```
document.getElementById('webform-created-id-here').getElementsByTagName('legend').getElementsByTagName('a');
```

I feel like I'm not understanding how to properly access that part of the DOM.  Can anyone offer help or suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByTagName return a nodelist with the elements found, so you must select the index of the element

Example for the first element

```
var test = document.getElementById('webform-created-id-here').getElementsByTagName('legend')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
```

[DEMO VIEW](http://jsfiddle.net/xwyMx/1/)

Comment: Interesting -- this looks exactly like what I need but it's still not working.  Is there a way to find out if it's actually "[0]"?  Because probably it's not...

Comment: Post the HTML, then we can tell you what it should be. But if there's only one child of the specified type, it will be [0].

Comment: You must select the index according to the 'a' order in the element, and as @Barmar have write, post that html part

Answer (score 0):

Recurse through the DOM yourself. References to the children of any element are stored in the `childNodes` attribute which exist for every node.

```
function recurseDOM (el,test) {
    if (test(el)) {
        return el;
    }
    else {
        var children = el.childNodes;
        var result;
        for (var i=0; i<children.length; i+) {
            result = recurseDOM(children[i],test);
            if (result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is only one possible implementation that I wrote in the 2 minutes it took me to type out this answer. So it can probably use some improvements. But you get the idea.

Use it like this:

```
recurseDOM(document.body,function(el){
    if (el == something_something) { return 1}
    return 0
});
```

You can write a similar function to test parents:

```
function testParents (el, test) {
    var parent = el.parentNode;

    if (test(parent)) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        if (parent != document.body) {
            return testParents(parent,test);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So you can write something like:

```
recurseDOM(document.body,function(el){
    if (el.tagName == 'a' && testParents(el,function(p){
        if (p.tagName == 'legend' && testParents(p,function(pp){
            if (pp.id == 'webform-created-id-here') {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        })) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    })) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Alternatively, you can start the recursion form the `getElementById` instead of `document.body`.